# Appending in Knockout Array giving duplicate rows

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, tablesorter

Adding new row to an knockout observable array which is sorted using Jquery TableSorter adds the rows twice,which causes duplication of the already existing rows.PFB my code:

```
<tbody  data-bind="foreach: jarFiles">  //jarFiles:KnockoutArray        
                <td><span data-bind="text: fileName"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                <td>...</tbody>
```

The sorting is applied on click on the first two rows:

```
$( "#fileName" ).click(function() {                                                     
    $("#display").tablesorter();
}//Invokes tablesorter on click function for fileName column
```

After the sorting i try to update the array which is in Tabular format, it returns duplicates:

```
        that._replace = function(newList) {//newList=oldList+newelement             
                    that.jarFiles.removeAll()   
                    var i=newList.length;
                    _.each(newList, function(jar){
                        that.jarFiles.push(jar); 
                    });
```

The page gets loaded using ajax.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to use knockout... what is needed is to trigger an "update" after the new content has been added - `$('#display').trigger('update');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593367/how-to-work-with-jquery-table-sorter-with-knockout

Comment: triggering the update isn't helping. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 that._replace = function(newList) {
    that.jarFiles.removeAll();  
    $(".display").find('tbody').empty(); // To clear table body
    _.each(newList, function(jar){ 
        that.jarFiles.push(jar); 
    });
    $(".display").trigger("update"); // To update the tablesorter
};
```